# Keeping app in background using xcui Test

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcuitest

I am trying to keep my app in background when one test is done then open app again from back ground to see notification screen

Appreciate your response

Thanks
Sri

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: used spring board static let springboard = XCUIApplication(privateWithPath: nil, bundleID: "com.apple.springboard") able to navigate to settings screen with XCUIApplication(privateWithPath: nil, bundleID: "com.apple.Preferences") but trying to see is there any other apps are running on background

Comment: There are `XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)` and `XCUIApplication().activate()`, but I think I didn't get the part of your message about "to see notification screen".